# Dominique Ansel book - ambiguity in the recipe

Tags: baking, melting-chocolate, cookbook, glaze

I have this book [https://www.amazon.com/Everyone-Can-Bake-Simple-Recipes/dp/1501194712](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1501194712) at home. And I wanted to try the "White Chocolate Glaze" from page 253.

But I am baffled about this step:

> 2. Make the syrup: Combine the glucose, sugar, and 60 grams (¼ cup) water in a medium saucepan and clip a digital thermometer to the side of the pan. Bring to a boil over high heat. Cook until the mixture reaches 113º to 122ºF (45º to 50ºC), about 10 minutes. Stir in the gelatin mixture with a spatula until incorporated. Remove from the heat.

These steps seem in contradiction to each other. How should they be interpreted so I may proceed?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would assume a typo - change one(!) letter and the logic fits again:

> Bring to a boil over high heat.
> Coo**l** until the mixture reaches 113º to 122ºF (45º to 50ºC), about 10 minutes. Stir in the gelatin mixture

Further explanation:

- If something is unclear and temperature is involved, you need to always check for a °F/°C mixup, but given the “45° to 50°C”, which matches the numbers in °F, we can pretty much exclude that.
- Gelatin should never be boiled, because then it loses its binding/thickening properties, dissolving in warm liquid is standard procedure.

So as we have confirmed that the target temperature is what the writer intended, the only way to get there from boiling is by letting the mixture **cool** down.

Comment: There's also the nonsensical "remove from heat" instruction at the end to contend with...